# Java Spring is not able to update Firebase DB after sometimes

Tags: java, spring, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am using Firebase with Java Spring and Tomcat8. My firebase auth rule is

```
{
    "rules": {
        ".read": "auth!=null",
        ".write": "auth!=null"

    }
}
```

I created a singleton class in my java spring application to load the firebase configuration and enabled Anonymous login. The problem occurs after few hours of deploying the server. When I deploy the WAR file, it updates the database for few hours, and after few hours it  fails. Then I need to reload the server context.
I got to know the session expires every 24 hours, but it's also causing problem before 24 hours.

**Things I tried**

1. Changed the **".write":true** in auth rules
2. Set Up a cron job for each 25 hours to initialise the singleton instance just after deploying the server.

**CronJob Instance Initialisation Code :**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/cronJob/reloadSession", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    @ResponseBody
    public BasicResponse reloadSession(HttpServletRequest request) {
        BasicResponse response = new BasicResponse();
        FirebaseManager.INSTANCE = new FirebaseManager();
        return response;
    }
```

**Firebase Manager : Singleton Class Code**

```
package com.dolphino.webapp.manager;

import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.Async;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp;
import com.google.firebase.FirebaseOptions;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;

@Service
public class FirebaseManager {

    public static FirebaseManager INSTANCE = new FirebaseManager();

    private static String FIREBASE_PATH = "/firebaseConnection.json";

    private static FirebaseOptions options;
    public FirebaseManager(){
        super();
        try{
            InputStream in = MobileManager.class.getResourceAsStream(FirebaseManager.FIREBASE_PATH);
            options = new FirebaseOptions.Builder()
                      .setServiceAccount(in)
                      .setDatabaseUrl("https://my-url.firebaseio.com/")
                      .build();     
            FirebaseApp.initializeApp(options);
        }catch(Exception e){
            //throw exception
        }
    }

    @Async
    public void saveUser(String parentId, String text){
            DatabaseReference mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
            mDatabase.child("users").child(parentId).setValue(text);
    }       
}
```

I have also tried to keep the **saveUser** method in another class, and auto wired it. But still it doesn't work.

The tomcat8 server log :

```
logs/catalina.2016-09-15.log:21:15-Sep-2016 12:08:18.765 WARNING [http-nio-8443-exec-57] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.clearReferencesThreads The web application [project-spring] appears to have started a thread named [MongoCleaner560407163] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
logs/catalina.2016-09-15.log:24:15-Sep-2016 12:08:18.766 WARNING [http-nio-8443-exec-57] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.clearReferencesThreads The web application [project-spring] appears to have started a thread named [FirebaseDatabaseWorker] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
logs/catalina.2016-09-15.log:34:15-Sep-2016 12:08:18.766 WARNING [http-nio-8443-exec-57] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.clearReferencesThreads The web application [project-spring] appears to have started a thread named [FirebaseDatabaseEventTarget] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
logs/catalina.2016-09-15.log:43:15-Sep-2016 12:08:18.766 WARNING [http-nio-8443-exec-57] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.clearReferencesThreads The web application [project-spring] appears to have started a thread named [java-sdk-http-connection-reaper] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
logs/catalina.2016-09-15.log:46:15-Sep-2016 12:08:24.944 INFO [http-nio-8443-exec-57] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.reload Reloading Context with name [/project-spring] is completed
```